# Selenium is unable to locate any element in html page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a small java app. that can log in to my university portal, I used Selenium in the following code:

```
 //some import statements 
 public class Portal{
     public Portal(){
          File file = new File("C:/chromedriver.exe");
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());

          HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
          String target = "http://portal.kfupm.edu.sa/cp/home/loginf";
          driver.get(target); 

          ArrayList <WebElement> inputs =   (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("input"));
          System.out.println(inputs.size());
          for(WebElement input : inputs){
                System.out.println(input.getAttribute("value") + "  " + input.getAttribute("name"));

          // to insure the link is displaying something
               ChromeDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
                driver1.get(driver.getCurrentUrl()); 

      }
      public static void main(String [] args){
          new Portal();
      }

 }
```

the problem is when I use this target (my university portal) I get inputs.size() = 0;  although, I'm sure there are elements with (input) tagName. Also I get the same resulst whatever was the method of (By) class I used.
  However, when I change the target to any link (for example: "http://www.google.com" or "http://www.facebook.com" , I get elements in the inputs ArrayList (all elements of tagName (input) that are in the target html page). Can any body please tell me what is the problem and how can I solve it? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you find zero elements with tag input is that all the elements lie inside a frame tag. Selenium is able to see to current window and all the elements that are defined inside frame tag (i.e. are inside a frameset) are invisile to it.

To see the element you will need to switch frame first, So that selenium has control inside the target frame and not in the outer window. Try this

```
driver.swtichTo().frame(0); // this will move selenium control inside first frame
```

Comment: It works fine as long as HtmlUnitDriver is not used. When I use it I don't get all elements tagged by input. I only get 1 element, and for some other locators I don't get any element when I use HtmlUnitDriver but I get them using ChromeDriver. Is there a difference in switching driver between HtmlUnitDriver and ChromeDriver. I really appreciate your help and your time.

Comment: might seem stupid but the problem was because I forgot to setJavascriptEnabled to true.. now it's solved :)